# How to display an image saved as blob in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, filereader

I wrote a function that saves an image as blob:

```
render() {
  ...
  return (
    ...
      <input
        accept="image/*"
        onChange={this.handleUploadImage.bind(this)}
        id="contained-button-file"
        multiple
        type="file"
      />
)}
```

and this is the function called in onChange:

```
  handleUploadImage(event) {
    const that = this;
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      that.setState({
        image: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        userImage: reader.result,
      });
    };
  }
```

I think this works fine because it saves in DB because the document has a field called image which looks like this: `blob:http://localhost:3000/80953c91-68fe-4d2a-8f5e-d9dd437c1f94`

this object can be accessed like `this.props.product`, to access the image it is `this.props.product.image`

The problem is when I want to show the image, I don't know how to do this.

I tried to put it in render like:

```
  {
    this.props.product.image ? (
      <img alt="" src={this.props.product.image} />
    ) : (
      null
    );
  }
```

it throws this error:

[image]

and the header:
[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried rendering the image source in [base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa)?

Comment: On a side note: `onChange={this.handleUploadImage.bind(this)}` will create a new function on every render. You can optimise this by only binding once in the constructor of your component.

Comment: @haensl I only tried the way I presented in the question. How should it be rendered like that? with `btoa`?

Comment: `<img alt="" src={btoa(this.props.product.image)} />`

Comment: if I remember correctly, you cannot use local files because of security concerns. but this would be logged in the console if that would be the reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should try URL.createObjectURL(blob)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

```
myImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Worked! , another important thing is to add `responseType: "blob"` to the request if using axios

Comment: It is worth noting that you should -have to- revoke the object when not needed especially in single page applications where the document isn't unloaded for an extended period of time. Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL