# Blob to image not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, base64, fetch-api

Fetched the blob using 'fetch' but after converting it to base64 then to image, it doesn't show up. I also tried using axios, but the same thing happens. I tried [this](https://reactnativeforyou.com/how-to-show-base64-data-as-image-in-react-native/) and it works just fine. I also tried this [site](https://www.base64decode.net/base64-image-decoder) to see if there is a problem with the blob I am trying to retrieve, but it also seems to work just fine. Tried checking if it did not retrieve the blob, but it does.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Image, Button, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [imageSource, setImageSource] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => { 
    fetchAndDisplayImage();
  }, []);

  const fetchAndDisplayImage = async () => {
    try { 
      const apiUrl = 'http://mywebsite.com/getImage.php?id=1';

      const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Image download failed.');
      }

      const blob = await response.blob(); 
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = () => {
        const base64DataUrl = reader.result; 
        // Set the image source with data URI scheme
        setImageSource({ uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64DataUrl.split(',')[1]}` }); 
      }; 
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching and displaying image:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {imageSource ? (
        <Image source={imageSource} style={styles.image} />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.placeholder}>
          <Text>No Image Available</Text>
        </View>
      )}
      <Button title="Fetch and Display Image" onPress={fetchAndDisplayImage} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
  placeholder: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ccc', 
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62181484/4549166

Comment: You _really_ should not be using any kind of Base64 encoding here. A `Blob` object is raw binary data, just pass that around and use `URL.createObjectURL()` to use it with an `<img/>` or other HTML. **Do not use Base64 nor `data:` URIs for images, videos, or anything larger than a kilobyte or so**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display an image saved as blob in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62180774/how-to-display-an-image-saved-as-blob-in-react)